# Provide counterfeit data protection for end users of service – tools?

Tags: database, hash, blockchain, database-backups

I need to create a service but i need a help with choice of tools.

Imagine service in which users create some data that have value in historical view (e.g. transactions). Other users can see this data but they need a proof that data are real and not falsified by users or even by service.

Example:

1. User A creates record with number 42
2. Couple of months passes
3. User B see this record and wants to be sure that service can't update this record with any other number 37

Service has trust window with 24 hours: it even can change users data, which were made on this day.

**Question:** Which instruments can help me to achieve that?

---

I was thinking about doing public daily backups (or reports?) that any user can download. From each report hash will be calculated and inserted into next backup – thus, a chan of hashes created. If service will change something in past, then hashes in this chain will not converge. Of course, i'll create open sourced tool for easy comparing diff between data and check if chain is valid.

**Point of trust:** there is one thing that i'm afraid of. Service can use many databases simultaneously and update all backups with all hashes one time (because first backup has no hash of previous one). So, to cover that case too, i think of storing hashes in some place that service can't change at all. For example, in one of the existed blockchains (btc, eth, ...) from official wallet of service. Or, maybe, DAG with some blockchain like IOTA?

---

1. What do you think of point of trust?
2. Can i achieve my goal with some simpler way (without blockchain)? And which one?
3. What are bottlenecks in this logic?

Comment: can you explain a bit on #3 of examples i.e.  `User B see this record and wants to be sure that service can't update this record with any other number 37`

Comment: That's one example with three steps.
Let's say that Bob creates record with created record "42".
Then Alice see number "42" and she wants to be sure that service didn't update this record silently.
If service updates Bob's record to "37" – then Alice can check this and point on that data was falsified.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 participating variables here

1. timestamp at which the record is created.
2. the data.

Solution premise,

1. Tampering proof.
2. the data can be changed in the same GMT calendar day without violating tamper-proof guarantee. (can be changed to a fixed window after creation)
3. RDBMS as the data store, (can be changed to any NoSQL with minor mods, but the idea remains the same).
4. Doesn't depend on any other mechanism which can be faulty or error-prone.
5. Single query verification.

### ## Proposed solution

#### create data table

```sql
CREATE TABLE TEST(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
DATA VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
CREATED_AT DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
);
```

#### create checksum table, which monitor tempering

```sql
CREATE TABLE SIGN(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
DATA_ID INT NOT NULL,
SIGNATURE  VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
CREATED_AT DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
UPDATED_AT TIMESTAMP
);
```

#### create trigger on insert of data

```sql
/** Trigger on insert */
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER sign_after_insert
AFTER INSERT 
ON TEST FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
-- INSERT VAL 
INSERT INTO SIGN(DATA_ID, `SIGNATURE`) VALUES(
NEW.ID, MD5(CONCAT (NEW.DATA, DATE(NEW.CREATED_AT)))
);
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

#### Create a trigger for update of data

```sql
-- UPDATE TRIGGER
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER SIGN_AFTER_UPDATE
AFTER UPDATE 
ON TEST FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
-- UPDATE VALS
IF (NEW.DATA <> OLD.DATA) AND (DATE(OLD.CREATED_AT) = CURRENT_DATE() ) THEN
UPDATE SIGN SET SIGNATURE=MD5(CONCAT(NEW.DATA, DATE(NEW.CREATED_AT))) WHERE DATA_ID=OLD.ID;
END IF;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

### Test

#### Step 1: insert the data

```sql
INSERT INTO TEST(DATA) VALUES ('DATA2');
```

The signature of data and the date at which it was created, will reflect as the signature in `SIGN` table.

#### Step 2: update the data

the signature will get updated if value is changed and it is the **SAME DAY**.

```sql
UPDATE TEST SET DATA='DATA' WHERE ID =1;
```

#### Step 3: validate

you can always validate the data signature as

```sql
SELECT MD5(CONCAT (T.DATA, DATE(T.`CREATED_AT`))) AS CHECKSUM, S.SIGNATURE FROM TEST AS T ,SIGN AS S WHERE S.DATA_ID= T.ID AND S.`id`=1;
```

#### Output

| CHECKSUM |    SIGNATURE |
| ------ | ------ |
|2bba70178abdafc5915ba0b5061597fa   |2bba70178abdafc5915ba0b5061597fa

Comment: What about situation when I want to falsify some point in history? Change system time, boot in the past, make queries with different data? How can user know about that?